# Labels on the different sides of svg rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to label my diagram [Waterfall_Chart](https://jsfiddle.net/Slava32/x5f5xpyb/8/) so that it shows the value in the right of the rectangle if it's positive and on the left side if it's negative.

On the lines 197-198 in the code I do it the following way:

```
label.selectAll("tspan")
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x(d.value1) + (d.value0 < d.value1 ? 5 : -25);
    }); 
    // 5px space from the right of the rect to (positive) label : 
    // -38px space from the lefr of the rect to (negative) label;
```

It works fine with small numbers, but when I have big numbers, the labels intersect with rectangles.

```js
var margin = {top: 30, right: 200, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatChange = d3.format("+d"),
    formatValue = d3.format("d");

var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
 .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [{id:"name1",val1:23,val2:344224},
  {id:"name2",val1:26544,val2:13222},
  {id:"name3",val1:15433,val2:154324},
  {id:"name4",val1:22453,val2:1654437},
  {id:"name5",val1:23213,val2:154325},
  {id:"name6",val1:254321,val2:22457},
  {id:"name7",val1:22344,val2:32353},
  {id:"name8",val1:13222,val2:245329}];
 

//d3.requestCsv("data_WfH.csv", function(error, data) {

  var values = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "id";}); 
  
data.forEach(function(d) {
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 d.value = +d[values[i]];
  return d;}});

var value1Sum = 0,
    value2Sum = 0;
 
 value1Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[0]];});
    value2Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[1]];});

 data = function (array) {
            r = array.map(function (d) {
                return { id: d.id, value: d[values[1]] - d[values[0]] };
            });
        return [{ id: values[0], value: value1Sum }].concat(r, { id: values[1], value: value2Sum });
    }(data);
 
  data.reduce(function(v, d) { return d.value1 = (d.value0 = v) + d.value; },0);
  
/*---------- Setting Up Dynamic Scales ----------*/
  
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.value0;}), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value0; })])
                .range([0, width]);
    
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data.map (function(d) { return d.id; }))
                .range([0, height])
    .padding(0.1);

/*---------- Build the Waterfall Diagram's rectangles ----------*/   
   
  svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
 .style("stroke", "gray") // stroke color for all rects
 .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "green";} // color rect with positive value in green if condition is true (1)
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "red";} // color rect with negative value in red if condition is true (1)
   else {return "gray";} // color rect in gray if both previous conditions are false (0)
   }) 
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.id); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { if (d.value!==value2Sum) {return x(d.value0 < d.value1 ? d.value0 : d.value1); }})
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value0 < d.value1 ? x(d.value1) - x(d.value0) : x(d.value0) - x(d.value1); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
   
   //при наводці курсора змінює колір ректів крім першого
      .on ( "mouseover" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
 .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "#84E884";} 
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "#FFA8A8";}
   else {return "#E8E8E8";} }); })
 . on ( "mouseout" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "green";} 
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "red";} 
   else {return "gray";} }); });

/*---------- Fill first rect with gray color ----------*/
   
  d3.select("rect")     // choose the first rect
 .style("fill", "#A2A2A2") // color it in gray

 //при наводці курсора змінює колір першого ректа
 . on ( "mouseover" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", "#E8E8E8")})
 . on ( "mouseout" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", "grey")});
 
    
/*---------- First vertical line ----------*/

//var minX =data[0].value;//select first value 

svg.append("g")
   .append("line")
 .style("stroke","gray")
 .attr("x1", x(value1Sum))
 .attr("y1", 2)
 .attr("x2",x(value1Sum))
 .attr("y2", height + 50);

/*---------- Last vertical line ----------*/ 
 
//var maxX = d3.sum(data, function(d){if (d.value!==value2Sum) {return d.value;}});

svg.append("g")
    .append("line")
 .style("stroke","gray")
 .attr("x1", x(value2Sum))           
 .attr("y1", 2)
 .attr("x2", x(value2Sum))
 .attr("y2", height + 50);
 
/*---------- Count the change ----------*/ 

var change = Math.round(value2Sum-value1Sum);

svg.append("text") // append text
    .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .style("stroke", "black")
 .style("position","middle")
 .attr("x", x(change/2+value1Sum)) // set x position of left side of text
    .attr("y", height + 40) // set y position of bottom of text 
    .text(change);
 
/*---------- Left Arrow ----------*/

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/ArrowRight.png")
    .attr("x", x(value1Sum)-37)
    .attr("y", height+15)
 .attr("width", 37)
    .attr("height", 37); 
 
/*---------- Right Arrow ----------*/ 

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/ArrowLeft.png")
    .attr("x", x(value2Sum))
    .attr("y", height+15)
 .attr("width", 37)
    .attr("height", 37);
 
/*---------- Label the diagram ----------*/
  
  var label = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.id) + y.bandwidth(); });

/*---------- Label the first element ----------*/

svg.append("text")
 .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .attr("x", x(value1Sum)/2)
    .attr("y", 20)
 .text(function(d) {return Math.round(value1Sum);});
 
/*---------- Label the last element ----------*/

svg.append("text")
 .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .attr("x", x(value2Sum)/2)
    .attr("y", height-5)
 .text(function(d) {return Math.round(value2Sum);}); 
   
/*---------- Label the value from the table ----------*/   
   
 label.append("tspan")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("dy", "-.3em")
      .text(function(d) { 
   if (d.value!==value1Sum & d.value!==value2Sum) {
   return formatChange(d.value1 - d.value0); }});

  label.selectAll("tspan")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value1) + (d.value0 < d.value1 ? 5 : -25); }); // 5px space from the right of the rect to (positive) label : -38px space from the lefr of the rect to (negative) label; 

 svg.append("g") // the following set of svg attributes visualizes Y axis
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(2)); // deleted .tickPadding(x(0) + 6) which wrote labels of axis y on the right side of the axis.


//}
//)
;
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: black; /*with fill: none; the axis line is thin, and without 'color'*/
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.label {
  fill: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.label-change {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label-value {
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
}

.label--negative {
 
}
```

```html
<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.9.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`text-anchor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) attribute to determine how the text should be displayed relative to your rectangles :

- if it should be displayed to the right, set `text-anchor` to `start` and it will be displayed as it already is
- if it should be displayed to the left, set `x` to a position slightly to the left of the rect and set `text-anchor` to `end`

Here's an example

```
label.selectAll("tspan")
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
        var rect = d3.select("#rect-" + d.id); // get the rect
        var rectx = parseInt(rect.attr('x')),  // x position
            rectwidth = parseInt(rect.attr('width')); // width
        if (!rectx) return 0;

        if (d.value0 < d.value1)
            // place the text to the right of the rect
            return rectx + rectwidth + 5;
        else
            // place the text to the left of the rect
            return rectx - 5; 
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
        return (d.value0 < d.value1) ? "start" : "end";
    });
```

Note that I [set an id on the rects to reference them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507394/1071630) and avoid recalculating the values

A Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8yv9dzpc/ and a snippet

```js
var margin = {top: 30, right: 200, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatChange = d3.format("+d"),
    formatValue = d3.format("d");

var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
 .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [{id:"name1",val1:23,val2:344224},
  {id:"name2",val1:26544,val2:13222},
  {id:"name3",val1:15433,val2:154324},
  {id:"name4",val1:22453,val2:1654437},
  {id:"name5",val1:23213,val2:154325},
  {id:"name6",val1:254321,val2:22457},
  {id:"name7",val1:22344,val2:32353},
  {id:"name8",val1:13222,val2:245329}];
 

//d3.requestCsv("data_WfH.csv", function(error, data) {

  var values = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "id";}); 
  
data.forEach(function(d) {
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 d.value = +d[values[i]];
  return d;}});

var value1Sum = 0,
    value2Sum = 0;
 
 value1Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[0]];});
    value2Sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d[values[1]];});

 data = function (array) {
            r = array.map(function (d) {
                return { id: d.id, value: d[values[1]] - d[values[0]] };
            });
        return [{ id: values[0], value: value1Sum }].concat(r, { id: values[1], value: value2Sum });
    }(data);
 
  data.reduce(function(v, d) { return d.value1 = (d.value0 = v) + d.value; },0);
  
/*---------- Setting Up Dynamic Scales ----------*/
  
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.value0;}), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value0; })])
                .range([0, width]);
    
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data.map (function(d) { return d.id; }))
                .range([0, height])
    .padding(0.1);

/*---------- Build the Waterfall Diagram's rectangles ----------*/   
   
  svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return "rect-"+d.id; })
 .style("stroke", "gray") // stroke color for all rects
 .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "green";} // color rect with positive value in green if condition is true (1)
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "red";} // color rect with negative value in red if condition is true (1)
   else {return "gray";} // color rect in gray if both previous conditions are false (0)
   }) 
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.id); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { if (d.value!==value2Sum) {return x(d.value0 < d.value1 ? d.value0 : d.value1); }})
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value0 < d.value1 ? x(d.value1) - x(d.value0) : x(d.value0) - x(d.value1); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
   
   //при наводці курсора змінює колір ректів крім першого
      .on ( "mouseover" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
 .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "#84E884";} 
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "#FFA8A8";}
   else {return "#E8E8E8";} }); })
 . on ( "mouseout" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.value0 < d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "green";} 
            else if (d.value0 > d.value1 & d.value!==value2Sum) {return "red";} 
   else {return "gray";} }); });

/*---------- Fill first rect with gray color ----------*/
   
  d3.select("rect")     // choose the first rect
 .style("fill", "#A2A2A2") // color it in gray

 //при наводці курсора змінює колір першого ректа
 . on ( "mouseover" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", "#E8E8E8")})
 . on ( "mouseout" ,  function ( d , i )  { 
    d3 . select ( this ) 
        .style("fill", "grey")});
 
    
/*---------- First vertical line ----------*/

//var minX =data[0].value;//select first value 

svg.append("g")
   .append("line")
 .style("stroke","gray")
 .attr("x1", x(value1Sum))
 .attr("y1", 2)
 .attr("x2",x(value1Sum))
 .attr("y2", height + 50);

/*---------- Last vertical line ----------*/ 
 
//var maxX = d3.sum(data, function(d){if (d.value!==value2Sum) {return d.value;}});

svg.append("g")
    .append("line")
 .style("stroke","gray")
 .attr("x1", x(value2Sum))           
 .attr("y1", 2)
 .attr("x2", x(value2Sum))
 .attr("y2", height + 50);
 
/*---------- Count the change ----------*/ 

var change = Math.round(value2Sum-value1Sum);

svg.append("text") // append text
    .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .style("stroke", "black")
 .style("position","middle")
 .attr("x", x(change/2+value1Sum)) // set x position of left side of text
    .attr("y", height + 40) // set y position of bottom of text 
    .text(change);
 
/*---------- Left Arrow ----------*/

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/ArrowRight.png")
    .attr("x", x(value1Sum)-37)
    .attr("y", height+15)
 .attr("width", 37)
    .attr("height", 37); 
 
/*---------- Right Arrow ----------*/ 

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/ArrowLeft.png")
    .attr("x", x(value2Sum))
    .attr("y", height+15)
 .attr("width", 37)
    .attr("height", 37);
 
/*---------- Label the diagram ----------*/
  
  var label = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.id) + y.bandwidth(); });

/*---------- Label the first element ----------*/

svg.append("text")
 .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .attr("x", x(value1Sum)/2)
    .attr("y", 20)
 .text(function(d) {return Math.round(value1Sum);});
 
/*---------- Label the last element ----------*/

svg.append("text")
 .style("fill", "black") // fill the text with the colour black
    .style("font-size", "12px") // size of the text
 .attr("x", x(value2Sum)/2)
    .attr("y", height-5)
 .text(function(d) {return Math.round(value2Sum);}); 
   
/*---------- Label the value from the table ----------*/   
   
 label.append("tspan")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("dy", "-.3em")
      .text(function(d) { 
   if (d.value!==value1Sum & d.value!==value2Sum) {
   return formatChange(d.value1 - d.value0); }});

  label.selectAll("tspan")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        var rect = d3.select("#rect-" + d.id);
        var rectx = parseInt(rect.attr('x')), 
         rectwidth = parseInt(rect.attr('width'));
        if (!rectx) return 0;
        if (d.value0 < d.value1)
         return rectx + rectwidth + 5;
        else
         return rectx - 5;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
        return (d.value0 < d.value1) ? "start" : "end";
      });

 svg.append("g") // the following set of svg attributes visualizes Y axis
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(2)); // deleted .tickPadding(x(0) + 6) which wrote labels of axis y on the right side of the axis.


//}
//)
;
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: black; /*with fill: none; the axis line is thin, and without 'color'*/
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.label {
  fill: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.label-change {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label-value {
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
}

.label--negative {
 
}
```

```html
<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.9.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it after calculating the length of label that need to be displayed.

Negative values `(-7* (d.value1 + "").length)` here 7 is arbitrary number multiplied to the length of the string that need to displayed.

```
label.selectAll("tspan")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
           return x(d.value1) 
           + (d.value0 < d.value1 ? 5 
              : (-7* (d.value1 + "").length)); 
       })
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/x5f5xpyb/9/)